# How to fix error with install maven jar plugin dependency?

Tags: java, maven

I am making an application into a jar file in maven. However, when I pull the jar plugin repository from maven and run these three command in Terminal:

```
mvn clean
mvn compile
mvn package
```

At mvn package, I get this error.
Error:

```
    Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:3.1.0:jar (default-jar) on project A2ATest2: Execution default-jar of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:3.1.0:jar failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:3.1.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies at org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:jar:3.1.0 -> org.apache.maven:maven-archiver:jar:3.2.0: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven:maven-
archiver:jar:3.2.0: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven:maven-archiver:pom:3.2.0 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): No such host is known (
repo.maven.apache.org) -> [Help 1]
```

However, when I use the 2.4 version instead of the 3.1.0 version it works just fine. I'm not sure if its a bug, or if I did something wrong. Thanks again for your help

Comment: Internet problem?

Comment: Network / Proxy / Firewall issue: ` No such host is known ...`

Comment: @Antoniossss Thanks I think it might be do to the proxy at work.

Answer (score 3):

Maven is not being able to connect to repo.maven.apache.org "No such host is known"

Check your repository tag in `settings.xml` and also check your network connection and do a `mvn clean install`. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I faced same problem **it just got resolved instantly by installing maven** i.e adding maven path in windows environmental variable. Basically you need to  install maven(check how to install maven) to resolve this error, go to cmd and enter **mvn --version** to check if maven is already installed.

Comment: This was the answer that worked for me.