# Unknown host 'No such host is known (repo.maven.apache.org)'

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, gradle

I was creating a release build tomorrow and its was working fine. but today its not working. when try to create release **APK** this error is thrown. I am basically a react-native developer and didn't know why its coming here.

Comment: Somewhat related maybe: [How to fix error with install maven jar plugin dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52893714/how-to-fix-error-with-install-maven-jar-plugin-dependency)

Comment: Can you share the error it throw?